# Can't execute listCollections in collection level role based access in MongoDB using Robot 3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have enabled collection level access on my MongoDB database. I want my users to access their own collection(and not others) in the Database while connecting from Robo3T. But, after connecting to the database, Robo 3T won't allow to browse the collections list and pop the below error:

**Error:**

> ListCollections failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on
>   DssScheduler to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {},
>   cursor: {}, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db:
>   ...", code: 13, codeName: "Unauthorized" }

So, I tried to set the database privileges as below:

```
db.createRole({ role: "collAReadWrite", 
    privileges: [ 
        { resource: 
            { db: "MyDB", collection: "collA" 
            }, 
            actions: ["find","insert","update","remove"] 
        },
        { resource: 
            { db: "MyDB", collection: "collB" 
            }, 
            actions: ["find"] 
        },
        { resource: 
            { db: "MyDB", collection: "collC" 
            }, 
            actions: ["find"] 
        }   
    ], 
    roles: [] 
})
```

I expected this to work as I gave read access to the user for all the collections but write access to only collectionA. After this I assigned the user the above role using the command below:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "collAUser",
    pwd: "collAUserPassxxxxxxx",
    roles: [ { role: "collAReadWrite", db: "MyDB" } ]
  }
)
```

Still Robo 3T pops the same error up.

Would appreciate any help on this !

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to privileges[].

```
{ resource: 
    { db: "MyDB", collection: "" }, 
      actions: ["listCollections"] } 
}
```

Listing collections will show all collections in the db, not just those the user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a change in MongoDB 4.0, Studio 3T or Robo 3T users running a server instance of MongoDB 4.0+ who experience incomplete collection listings are kindly asked to review the privileges of the corresponding MongoDB database user account.

Please make sure that sufficient privileges - which allow a user to list the collections of a database - have been assigned. One possible fix is to update a user's roles to include the privilege to run the operation/action "listCollections" on a database.